# Resize initial 100vh container

Tags: html, css

Say we have the following layout structure

```
<div class="full-height>
 <nav>....</nav>
 <section class="hero>...</section>
</div>
<section class="other-content>....</section>

.full-height {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 .nav {
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
 }
 .hero {
  background-image: .....;
  background-size: cover;
  flex: 1;
 }
}
```

I want the `nav` and `.hero` sections to initially take the full height of the viewport, but when I resize the browser, it should make room for the other section to come in below it.

If I wrap `nav` and `.hero` within a parent div and set that divs height to 100vh, it works as expected, but it will always take 100% height of the viewport on resize.

Comment: What's wrong with using media queries?

Comment: Please post your current css and indicate what is not working with it

Comment: @Huangism included css. The problem is `full-height` always takes 100vh on resize, not making room for `.other-content`. I only want to initially take up 100vh but only on certain breakpoints.

Comment: What `.hero` section...there is none in your code?

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of media queries but you can learn about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: *"... but when I resize the browser, it should make room for the other section to come in below it."* So are we supposed to know at which point the 3rd div starts making its appearance? Is it as soon as the viewport is resized? Or is there a magical height of the top 2 divs got to be first?